# Not able to executeScript in appiumdriver. However the script snippet works in Appium inspector. Is there any desired capability to fix this?

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I have an android screen that has an android-IME **onEditorAction** implemented. I am using appium for UI test automation. I am at a step where *I am able to execute a script via appium inspector. But I am not able to execute it from my Java project*. I am spawning appiumserver as a service. **Need community help** to know whether I am missing any desired capability in appiumDriver/appiumServer initialisation.

---

tools version

- Appium-java-client: 7.0.0
- jdk -  1.8.0_275, vendor: Amazon.com Inc.

**On Appium inspector**
[image: AppiumInspectorView]

*Same action scripted in Java as :*

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "done"));
```

Existing appiumdriver capabilities :

```
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, platform);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, platformVersion);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appPath);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "4000");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, "true");
            mobileDriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(url), cap);
```

Existing appiumServer capabilities:

```
    cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress(ip);
    builder.usingAnyFreePort();
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");
    builder.withArgument(() -> "--allow-insecure","chromedriver_autodownload");
    tlogger.info("About to start the appium service");
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();
```

On triggering the script snippet, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ! I missed to focus the textfield. After clicking the textbox mobileElement, the above script ran fine.